# Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem - original version and modern version difference?

Tags: signal-processing

I just found out that the original version of Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem differs from the modern version..

In the original version, it states that the bandlimited signal $x(t)$ can be constructed by the sampling rate of $2B$ when $B$ is the highest frequency content of the signal.

However, the modern version states that the signal can be constructed by the sampling rate of $2B$ when the signal's highest frequency content does not exceed or equal to $B$.

So, is the original version wrong? Or are there any reasons why these two came to differ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the signal $f(t) = \sin 2\pi Bt$. Sample at a $2B$ rate, ie, at the time points $t_k = \frac{k}{2B}$. Then you have $f(t_k) = 0$, $\forall k$. So the signal $f$ cannot be reconstructed from the samples (it is indistinguishable from the zero function at these samples).

Comment: that's what I thought.. Wikipedia says that Shannon's original statement was as mentioned, so that's why I was curious...

Answer (score 2):

What you call the modern version is the classical version. Your original version is wrong, as copper.hat explained, and the really modern version is studied under [compressed sensing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_sensing).